# Index.php called twice in one request

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a bug or something. I noticed it because my routing is called multiple times. After I removed many lines I ended up with only the index.php. The index.php now only has `$var=1;` in it, but it also triggers Xdebug multiple times.

Does someone has an idea how to fix it or why it occurs?

This is my Xdebug settings if that's the problem:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp2\tmp"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%u.%H_%R"
```

Comment: Check what requests are getting sent by the browser ("Network" tab of your browser's Dev Tools). One of the common reasons -- missing favicon (and your index.php handles that -- request to a non existing resource).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As LazyOne pointed out it was because the missing Favicon. Thank You. Fix was to add:

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
```